# Encapsulation of array with reference variables

Tags: java, arrays, encapsulation

I intend to write a program that simulates particles collisions in one or more dimension. For the 2D case, I would also like to make a GUI that shows the particles.

I have a main class, `ParticleCollider`, which contains an inner class, `Particle`, an array of said `Particles`as well as some methods for updating the positions and velocities of the particles. The class roughly looks like this:

```
class ParticleCollider {

     class Particle {
          private double mass;
          private double[] pos;
          //plus some other private class variables
          public Particle(double mass, double[] pos) {
               this.mass = mass; 
               this.pos = pos;
          }
     }

     private Particle[] pArray;

     //Details of constructor are irrelevant
     public ParticleCollider() {

     }

     //Do stuff to particles in pArray, i.e. change their positions and velocitites
     public void update() {
          //For example
          pArray[0].pos[0] = 0;
     }

}
```

In the graphics class, I want to be able to access the `Particles` so that I can find their positions and radii for drawing purposes. One way would of course be to add a method `getParticles`in `ParticleCollider`to return the array of `Particles`, `pArray`. My question is now if this would be considered a violation of encapsulation. Because the `Particle`class has no setters, I cannot change the `Particles`. Also, because an array hase fixed length, I cannot add any `Particles`. The only thing I could do, which I guess is pretty bad, is take some `Particle`and assign it the value of `null`.

**EDIT**
It has been suggested that I use a List instead of an array and provide an iterator to said List. It would seem to me that this would not solve the encapsulation problem. Regardless, I'm relucant to abandon the array because I need to be able to select a random `Particle` in the collection of `Particles` and then iterate it cyclically.

Comment: Note that since `pArray` is an array.  If you return it, the one it has been returned to can change the elements at will.  If this concerns you, you should also note that the `Particle` constructor simply stores away a reference that still can be modified from the outside.

Comment: How about: Using a list instead of an array and provide an interator over all Particles (Iterable), not allowing to modify the list if not intended...

Comment: Not related, but that inner class should be static if it does not depend on an instance of Collider. If you use it outside of the Collider class (as it seems to be the case), I would even declare it in a separate file.

Comment: @5gon12eder Well, that's the issue.

Comment: @Jens-PeterHaack Would I not be able to modify the elements of the list from an iterator? E.g. iterator.next().remove()

Comment: @Joffrey Yes, you may be right about declaring Particle in a separate file. In that case I will have to provide it with setters, which will make encapsulation even harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using this pattern:

```
    public class Particle {
        // Particle code
    }

    public class Particles implements Iterable<Particle> {
        ArrayList<Particle> myParticles = new ArrayList<Particle>();

        public void add(Particle particle) { myParticles.add(particle); }

        public Iterator<Particle> iterator() {
            return myParticles.iterator();
        }

        // more code on particles
    }

    void bla() {
        Particles particles = new Particles();
        particles.add(new Particle());
        particles.add(new Particle());

        for (Particle particle : particles) {
            System.out.println("P="+particle);
        }
    }
```

If you want to inhibit the remove() on this iterator you might use this pattern:

```
    public static class Particles implements Iterable<Particle> {
        ArrayList<Particle> myParticles = new ArrayList<Particle>();

        public void add(Particle particle) { myParticles.add(particle); }

        public Iterator<Particle> iterator() {
            return new Iterator<Particle>() {
                Iterator<Particle> listIterator = myParticles.iterator();

                @Override
                public boolean hasNext() {
                    return listIterator.hasNext();
                }

                @Override
                public Particle next() {
                    return listIterator.next();
                }

                @Override 
                public void remove() {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                }
            };
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I think it will work! I wonder however, why I cannot call particles.iterator().remove(). When I do so, I get IllegalStateException. Of course I don't want to be able to call particles.iterator().remove(), I just wonder what prevents me from doing this.

Comment: Unfortunately the remove() works on that iterator. If you have called next() on the iterator, a remove() is possible. check your code and also check the Iterator API for the explanation of IllegalStateException.

Comment: I updated the answer to include an option to inhibit the remove()